# Count number of students in a school in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
class School(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField()
 city = models.CharField()
 street = models.CharField()


class Student(models.Model):
 school_id =  models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 first_name = models.CharField()
 last_name = models.CharField()
```

I want to join two classes School and Student and get the number of students in these school, So I wrote this code in my serializers. but I got no resulte of number of students, only the two classes joined. Can someone help me?

serializers.py

```
from django.db.models import Count

class SchoolSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
    model = School
    fields = ['name']

class StudentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

  school = SchoolSerializer()

  school.objects.annotate(num_of_students=Count('student'))

  class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'school']
```

views.py

In my views I wrote the following code:

```
 class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = StudentSerializer
  queryset = Student.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

in your models.py add two method:

```
class School(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
     street = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

def count_of_students(self):
    return Student.objects.filter(school_id=self).count()

def students_in_school(self):
    return list(Student.objects.filter(school_id=self))

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.city}->{self.street}->{self.name}"


class Student(models.Model):
school_id = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

and in your serializers.py

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)


class SchoolSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
count_of_students = serializers.IntegerField()
name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
students_in_school = StudentSerializer(many=True)
```

and in your views.py:

```
def get_school(request, id):
school = School.objects.get(pk=id)
serilizer = SchoolSerializer(school)
json = rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer().render(serilizer.data)
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

and in your urls.py

```
    path('schools/<int:id>',get_school)
```

as example data you can call [enter link description here](http://127.0.0.1:8000/schools/1)

and here is sample output:

```json
{
   "count_of_students":9,
   "name":"S1",
   "students_in_school":[
      {
         "first_name":"surname_1",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      },
      {
         "first_name":"surname_2",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      },
      {
         "first_name":"surname_3",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      },
      {
         "first_name":"surname_4",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      },
      {
         "first_name":"surname_5",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      },
      {
         "first_name":"surname_6",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      },
      {
         "first_name":"surname_7",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      },
      {
         "first_name":"surname_8",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      },
      {
         "first_name":"surname_9",
         "last_name":"surname_{i}"
      }
   ]
}
```